# Selective logs via Rsyslog

Tags: logging, rsyslog

We know in /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
*.* @ip:port
```

will send all logs to that IPs, suppose we only need kernel and Auth.
Would it be

```
Kernel.*, Auth.* @ip:port
```

or

```
Kernel.* @ip:port
Auth.* @ip:port
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax using the *deprecated* rsyslog format would look like the following:

```
Kernel.*;Auth.* @ip:port
```

or like this in the *advanced* rsyslog format:

```
Kernel.*;Auth.* action(type="omfwd" target="192.0.2.1" port="10514" protocol="tcp")
```